# The most effective way of finding rank of item in a list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I have a table with *k* columns and *i* items, where 100 > *k* > 20 and 20000 > *i* > 10000.

I need to get *rank* by each column of each item and then process the value, which by naive algorithm means sorting by columns and looking up items in the sorted lists.

Function *rank* returns position of item in an ordered list.

So far it looks like:
Sorting **n*log(n)** *k*-times => k*(n*log(n))
Lookup **n^2** *k*-times => k*(n^2)

and that's just a rank().

This is really unacceptable for the application I am building, so I'd need a better idea how to compute or approximate the rank.

Comment: for each row you will calculate several ranks (one per column), how do you plan to sort items?

Comment: Can't you store the data in an optimally sorted way i.e. insert into a sorted collection and you then just have the lookup cost.

Comment: If the table is more or less static, you could use some sort of indexing, like a DBMS does, i.e. pre-calculate and store sorting orders by each column.

Comment: actually lookup in sorted list should be logn

Comment: @Lashane I can sort by column0, get ranks, then by column1, get ranks and so on. Final sorting will be done from calculated data (from ranks and static weights). And yeah, you're right. Lookup in sorted list would be logn. Thanks

Comment: @cristobalito I'd have to store the data k times and look up n items, so I'd be still there.

Comment: first optimization I see - as soon as you have sorted list, you can assign ranks to every item, without any lookup, so it will be only N

Comment: what types of columns you're using?

Comment: if you mean data types, all positive integers...

Comment: as soon as your columns are positive integers, you can use their values as rank without sorting

Comment: probably you could also calculate min/max for every column and use them to get "normalized" rank directly from value without sorting, like `(item.columns[i]-min[i]) / (max[i]-min[i]+1)`

Comment: No, that's what I am doing right now, and it doesn't work - final sorted order is different to what I am getting in reference excel spreadsheet using rank()

Comment: so, you want exact rank value, not approximate?

Comment: Hard to say, as of know I just know that I need at least better approximation than min-max normalisation provides. Took me some time to understand why the results are so different, but it makes a little bit of sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an array of indices 0 to i-1 for each column, then sort the indices according to the items in a column. Then convert the sorted indices into a rank using:

```
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        rank[sorted_index[j]] = j;
```

You may want to create a matrix of ranks.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, looking an element in a sorted list is log(n). If you look for an item in more than a O(n) complexity, there is something wrong.

Secondly, you could map your elements x to a pair (x, initialIndexBeforeSorting). Thus, after sorting your list, you can get in O(1) your "reverse lookup" (You go through your sorted column and for each item x, find back where it was and updating him his rank). O(n logn + n) instead of O(n logn + n logn).

Comment: trivial lookup by binary search wouldn't work here, because of same values should get same rank. so lookup item is O(n) * n items...

Comment: @notnull binary search could work too, with small adjustment - after you found index of item in array - go to left until you find minimal index for this value